# Formatting an Excel cell in currency

Tags: excel, excel-2010

how can I format a column of Excel values as currency using the following format

```
178014
212846
3845123
51212178
```

Desired results:

```
$1780.14
$2128.46
$38,451.23
$512,121.78
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has or hasn't worked? Why not just use, say, `Mid()` with `Text()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a **LEFT** and **RIGHT** function to update the values:

> ="$"&LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&"."&RIGHT(A1,2)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative

```
=TEXT(A1/100,"$###,##0.00")
```

[image]